# Publishing Jupyter notebook with SQL connection

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, rstudio-server, rstudio-connect

I'm trying to publish a jupyter notebook to Posit (Rstudio) connect with a SQL connection.  I've been using pyodbc without any luck.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                  'SERVER='+server +';'
                  'DATABASE=' + database +';' 
                  'UID=' + UID + ';'
                  'PWD=' + PWD + ';'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

I've also tried:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                  'SERVER='+server +';'
                  'DATABASE=' + database +';' 
                  'UID=' + UID + ';'
                  'PWD=' + PWD + ';'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

I was expecting for the connection to work the same way it did on my computer.  I know the posit connect server is able to access SQL Server because it's been done in R.  What am I missing?

Comment: Start with the obvious - has pyodbc been added to the server?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to import pyodbc without issues.  I just can't establish a connection.  I should have specified this, thanks.